# Abstract factory design pattern with default implementation

Tags: c++, design-patterns, abstract-class

I have to create family of objects based on customer type.
I have one base abstract class ApplicationRulesFactory, which defines 
virtual interface. A lot of concrete customer classes inherits from this class.

The problem is that for some customers say CustomerB we do not use the objects Rule2 and Rule3 because the features in the application which are using these objects Rule2 and Rule3 are disabled from the application user interface for that customer, so we are not really needing to instantiate these objects at all.

The simplified code is here, i.e in reality ApplicationRulesFactory has much more virtual methods, and more concrete customer classes that inherits from it :

```
class ApplicationRulesFactory
{
  virtual Rule1*  GetRule1() = 0;
  virtual Rule2*  GetRule2() = 0;
  virtual Rule3*  GetRule3() = 0;   
  .....
};

class ACustomerRulesFactory : public ApplicationRulesFactory
{
   Rule1* GetRule1()
   {
     return new ACustomerRule1();
   }

  Rule2 * GetRule2()
  {
    return new ACustomerRule2();
  }  

 Rule3* GetRule3()
 {
   return new ACustomerRule3();
 }  
};  

class BCustomerRulesFactory : public ApplicationRulesFactory
{
    Rule1* GetRule1()
    {
      return new BCustomerRule1();
    }
    Rule2* GetRule2() // not needed
    {
      // what to return here ?
    }  
    Rule3* GetRule3() // not needed
    {
     // what to return here ?
    }
};
```

So how should I go to implement this :

1) Return some default implementation  in the base class ApplicationRulesFactory  :

```
class ApplicationRulesFactory
{
  virtual Rule1*  GetRule1() = 0;
  virtual Rule2*  GetRule2()  { return new Rule2DefaultImpl();}
  virtual Rule3*  GetRule3()  { return new Rule3DefaultIml();}   
};
```

But this seems wrong, to inherit new classes(Rule1DefaultImpl,Rule2DefaultImpl) from Rule1, Rule2,  and probably make them with empty implementation just for the purpose of returnig them  like default implementation in the ApplicationRulesFactory

2) or in the concrete class return the default implementaion and leave these methods pure virtual in the base class

```
class BCustomerRulesFactory : public ApplicationRulesFactory
{
  Rule1* GetRule1()
  {
     return new BCustomerRule1();
  }

  Rule2* GetRule2() 
  {
    return new Rule2DefaultImpl();
  }

 Rule3* GetRule3() 
 {
    return new Rule3DefaultImpl();
 }
};
```

These solution also seems very ugly to redefine the methods in every concrete customer class although they are not needed.

3) Also I have a feeling that maybe I should not use inheritance like this, cause this violates the IS-A rule for inheritance, cause a significant number of the methods are not applicable to all of the concrete customer classes, but don' t how to go to implement this without inheritance.

Any ideas

Comment: They are pointers, could you not just return NULL? Design-wise, Customer A and B are different types of customer, so may be there should be 2 subclasses, one with 1 rule and another with 3.

Comment: Yes I can, but still suspect is this the right thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

If `ApplicationRulesFactory` doesn't make sense for certain kinds of `Customers`, then it isn't the right abstraction for you.

Your domain `knows` what makes sense, so why would it be asking for `Rule2` and `Rule3`?

Make the object which knows that it only needs `Rule1` use a factory which gives it `Rule1` only. Give it a context so that it can get the factory it needs.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing the interface and the factory into one. Surely the interface should be a class on its own, with various rules that have a default behaviour in the base-class and then an overridden behaviour in the derived class, and then the factory returns a pointer to the requested class that implements the right rules for that case.

But maybe I've misunderstood what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you, what you mean mixing the interface and the factory into one.

Comment: A typical factory function is something that returns an object from a number of classes [that are related to the same base-class and provide the same interface]. You give it a "selection criteria", and it picks the right class to create. The object returned represents the implementation of the selected type - e.g. "the rules that apply to this case". So, in this case, you'd feed in "customer type", and get back the rules applying to that customer in one object. But I'm still not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to actually do.

Answer (score 0):

If the rules can never be used, I would suggest just returning a null pointer from a base class implementation (mostly like your option one except not even bothering with a default implementation since it can never be called).